# How to search using input to find certain values in a sorted, nested list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, user-input, nested-lists

So right now I have a nested list that I've sorted using a bubble sort. The code looks something like this:

```
def bubbleTop5(bad_list):
    length = len(bad_list) - 1
    sorted = False
    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(length):
            if bad_list[i][1] <= bad_list[i+1][1]:
                sorted = False
                bad_list[i], bad_list[i+1] = bad_list[i+1], bad_list[i]
```

This sorts the lists based on their [1]th element and prints out a list similar to this:

```
[['California', 4964, 76, 22], ['Texas', 3979, 62, 23], ['New York', 1858, 69, 20], ['Virginia', 1655, 60, 19], ['Maryland', 1629, 66, 20]]
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is make the user input a number for the [3]th element in these lists and only show those states with that value. So if I were to input 7, then it would only show states with a value of 7 or higher in the [3]th element. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: So, what is the issue? Simply filter the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `raw_input` to get the input and a *list comprehension* to get the result:

```
key = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
result = [e for e in bad_list if e[3] >= key]
```

Note that `raw_input` will return a *string*, so you should convert it to an *integer* using `int(...)`.

Comment: So would I use this within the bubbleTop5() function? or outside it?

Comment: It depends on what the `bubbleTop5` is desired to do. But since it doesn't return any result, it is not useful. So probably, you would like to add a `return` statement in that function.

Comment: Why? Like `list.sort()`, `bubbleTop5(list)` modifies its argument in place, so does not need to return a result. In fact the general rule in Python is that mutating function/method calls should not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter search value: "))
result = [x for x in sorted_list if x[3] >= n]
```

Also note that your sort could be achieved with

```
sorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

For a large list this will generally be MUCH faster than a bubble sort written in Python.

Comment: the third element is `x[2]` :). Happens to all of us.

Comment: Apparently, every single answer has the same mistake :)

Comment: Jonathan actually wrote "the [3]th element".  Since he used "the [1]th element" to refer to element 1 I have simply been consistent. So I maintain it's NOT a mistake.

Comment: Ok, my bad :(. I maintain, happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

you can sort the list

```
 badlist=sorted(bad_list,key=lambda x :x[1])
```

n = int(raw_input("Enter search value: "))
take the input and you can use filter the elements which has greater than input element

```
result = filter(lambda x : x[3] >=n,sorted_list)
```